# Using law of sines/cosine AND vectors to solve this problem.

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

Erica bought a boat and wants to test it. She wants to travel 3141 miles Northwest of her current position forming an angle of 130. The boat will be traveling at 150 mph. She gets ready and fuels her boat for 3150 miles then realizes that there is a strong 40 miles/hour wind blowing from the Southwest at 40 degrees(positive x axis is 0 degrees). She needs to employ advanced mathematics to help her fuel her boat appropriately. You need to calculate the total distance she will travel assuming the wind continues to blow at 40 mph and the time for the trip.
Use Vectors for the solutions and then use the law of sines/cosines as another solution. I need both the workings.

Using the law of sines/cosines I'm getting ~4300 and with vectors, I'm getting ~76000 so there is a big disparity between the solutions even though they should be the same. 
Working so far: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M43Jc.jpg

Comment: Are you sure that, in your calculation, you have properly calculated with radians/ degrees?

Comment: yes, it all in degrees, but I think I'm messing up the vector addition. The law of sines answer makes sense but the vectors answer doesn't.

Comment: Can you edit your question so it contains the vector computation you have performed? That way I (and the community) can see what you have done and what might have gone wrong. By the way, this is adivsable to do in general when using stackexchange! Also, in your question, do you mean that she fuels the boat for 3.150 miles instead of 3150? This would make sense, since she wants to travel 3.141 miles. Or is the ","  in 3,141 used as a way to make large numbers more readable?

Comment: I see what you mean, I removed all the commas to make it friendly and added my working so far. (It is not perfect but the implementation is the same.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, a comment on your law of sines solution. I have redrawn (and corrected) your picture using GeoGebra, to be able to talk about it more comprehensively. Please note that it is only a sketch.
[image]

As you can see, the black angle I drew inside the triangle, differs from your black angle on the same spot, with mine being the correct one because of Z-angles. Thus you must first determine the non-black part of angle C before you can apply your method, which was fine otherwise, except that the value of the green angle is also wrong: what angle does AB make with the x-axis, viewed counterclockwise (thus the non-green angle)? Substract that from $180$ degrees to get the proper green angle.

---

Now let's take a look at your vector solution. You start by constructing the vectors from their length and their angle, which is good. Note that you know the green vector, not the blue one, since the green one represents the direction the person has to steer in to compensate for the blowing wind and in the question, it says that the person is traveling at 150 mph. Now let's take a look at the construction of the red vector. The construction of the green one is similar, just make sure to use the proper angle! I have provided a visualisation of the construction with the following picture:

[image]

Note that $\cos(40^\circ)=\frac{x}{40}$ and $\sin(40^\circ)=\frac{y}{40}$, so the red vector is given by $( 40\cdot\cos(40^\circ),40\cdot\sin(40^\circ) )$ instead of $(40+\cos(40^\circ),40+\sin(40^\circ))$, as in your answer. I notice that, for the computation of the blue vector, you use the distance traveled, not the speed, which explains the large difference in your answers (even though the way you used the blue vector is wrong in itself).

Now all you have to do is to compute the green vector using the proper speed; the rest of your method seems to be correct. I'm not quite sure I understand the "(21)" part in your answer, so I'll say this: your final answer should have the form $\sqrt{(x_{green}+x_{red})^2+(y_{green}+y_{red})^2}$.

I hope this helps. If some parts are still unclear to you, or if you notice a mistake, leave a comment on this answer and I will edit it accordinly.

Comment: I have been able to solve this question with the law of sines. Thanks! However, I have a problem with solving it using Vector Addition, here is a link to show how far I have gotten: http://imgur.com/a/wEsmz

Comment: I made all the angles into normal angles(moving from positive x-axis counterclockwise)… My question doesn't do it like that, though… The working should be the same but the numbers would be different.

Comment: No problem! First of all, does it make sense that the y-coordinate in the vector describing point B is negative? Think of a geometric interpretation (make a drawing). Also note that the vectors for boat speed and wind are without the t parameter, since now you have distance vectors (you use them correctly, it's just noteworthy that they are not speed vectors). Next, have you figured out the $\angle C$ in the picture in my answer? Using it, you can calculate the $x$ in your solution, even though you should also check if you have used it correctly (think geometrically).

Comment: I have figured out the law of sines problem. Whenever I solve with vector addition i am getting a cycling equation that doesn't seem to be solvable.

Comment: Using inner product: Let $\vec{w}=(40\cos(40),40\sin(40))$ represent wind veloicty, $\vec{d}=(-D\cos(50),D\sin(50))$ destinator velocity. Here $D$ is the speed (it's length). Calculate the inner product: $\vec{w}\cdot\vec{d}=|\vec{w}|*|\vec{d}|*\cos(\alpha)$, with $\alpha$ the angle between the two vectors. Note that $|\vec{d}|=D$ and $|\vec{w}|=40$ per definition. Next, calculate the inner product "the other way": $\vec{w}\cdot\vec{d}=x_w*x_d+y_w*y_d$. Now you can simply substitute the inner product and solve for D, getting the velocity of the destinator. With this, calculate the distance.

Comment: I had a random realisation that in the last sentence of my previous comment, I meant "calculate the time" instead of "calculate the distance", since the distance of the destinator is already known. How is the exercise coming along?